# Only front page shown?

Tags: configuration

I designed my site with Acquia Dev Desktop on my PC and now it's finished and I uploaded folder of my site to public_html folder in cpanel. I export my database on my computer and import it to my host. but now when I enter my url in address bar of a browser only front page shown, for example when I click on other content of my site it gos to a white page and nothing will loaded. 
what should I do? pleas help me.
which command of setting.php file should change after importing database on server?
this is my site: http://www.setareonline.ir

Comment: Your site shows HTTP 500 error now, so your question is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason can be missing .htaccess file in the drupal root directory or if it is present than possibly your web server is not able to read it. For example web server apache reads .htaccess file with help of mod_rewrite module or even if mod_rewrite module is installed on Apache , Apache server do not have Allow override all permissions. One of the way to check issue is related to .htaccess or not can be accessing internal pages with query parameter, for example www.yoursite.com?q=user and see if it works! then chances are issues with .htaccess file.just check you have shared the URL, for me reason looks like to be .htaccess file check your drupal install is having .htaccess file or not if so ask your web master to let your web server to read your .htacccess

Comment: thanks a million, yes, it was because of .htaccess file that I deleted because of my host. and asked my host provider and after making a change in .htaccess file and upload it it seems ok :)
thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the list WSOD (White screen of death)
[WSOD Drupal](https://drupal.org/node/158043)

Put this into your index.php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

it should be able to tell you whats wrong.

In your case, I can see that the URLS are not following. So you should look into your .htaccess file and check if the URLS are the same. 
Check out `RewriteBase /`